# How to remove inner margins from Matplotlib plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I'm trying to plot an audio waveform using PyQt5 and Matplotlib, and despite trying several suggestions from other questions, I can't get the inner margins to disappear. I must be doing something wrong.

The audio waveform should be touching the edges of the widget, but as you can see in this screengrab, there is a large black inner margin on all four sides:

[image: Audio waveform plot with large margins on all sides]

My code includes `tight_layout()` and `subplots_adjust()` calls from examples found online, but they don't seem to be having any effect. (The audio is maximised so the peak values should be hitting 100% of the available plot.)

Can somebody point out why the margins are still persisting please?

Full sample code:

```
import sys
import wave

import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QGridLayout
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class MatplotlibWidget(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MatplotlibWidget, self).__init__(Figure())
        self.setParent(parent)

        self.figure = Figure(tight_layout=True)
        self.figure.tight_layout(pad=0)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.plot = None

        self.figure.set_facecolor("black")
        mpl.rcParams["lines.linewidth"] = 1
        mpl.rcParams["lines.color"] = "b"

    def plotAudio(self, waveformData):
        self.plot = self.figure.add_subplot(111, position=[0, 0, 1, 1])
        self.plot.clear()
        self.plot.axis("off")
        self.plot.use_sticky_edges = True
        self.plot.set_title(None)
        self.plot.set_xlabel(None)
        self.plot.set_ylabel(None)
        self.plot.margins(0)
        self.figure.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, top=1, bottom=0, wspace=0, hspace=0)
        self.figure.tight_layout(pad=0)
        self.plot.plot(waveformData)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.draw()


class WaveformTest(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 tests'
        self.setMinimumSize(200, 200)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window |
                            QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint |
                            QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)

        self.label = QLabel("Waveform")
        self.waveformWidget = MatplotlibWidget()

        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.waveformWidget, 1, 0)

    def plotAudio(self, sourceFile):
        spf = wave.open(str(sourceFile), "r")
        signal = spf.readframes(-1)
        signal = np.fromstring(signal, "Int16")

        self.waveformWidget.plotAudio(signal)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = WaveformTest()
    ex.show()
    sourceFile = "C:\\temp\\937-01400_20200622091518.wav"
    ex.plotAudio(sourceFile)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to get might be obtained using the [xlim](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html) and [ylim](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html) methods inside your `plotAudio` function. Since I don't have your data set, I will show you its application in a hypothetical noisy function example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num = np.random.uniform(-np.pi, np.pi, 10000)
sig = np.sin(num) + np.random.normal(0, 1, 10000)

figure = plt.Figure(tight_layout=True)

plot = figure.add_subplot(111, position=[0, 0, 1, 1])
plot.axis("off")
plot.use_sticky_edges = True

plot.set_title(None)
plot.set_xlabel(None)
plot.set_ylabel(None)

plot.margins(0)
figure.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, top=1, bottom=0, wspace=0, hspace=0)
figure.tight_layout(pad=0)

plt.xlim([-np.pi, np.pi])
plt.ylim([sig.min(), sig.max()])

plt.scatter(num, sig)
plt.show()
```

Here I include the plots with and without the explicit limits (basically commenting out the lines I added to your matplotlib code):

[image: Without limits][image: With limits]

I hope this gives you some hints.

## Edit:

After debugging your code with the supplied input file, I found that something very close to the desired output can be found by modifying the `MatplotlibWidget` class like this:

```
class MatplotlibWidget(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MatplotlibWidget, self).__init__(Figure())
        self.setParent(parent)

        self.figure = Figure(constrained_layout=True)
        self.figure.set_facecolor("black")
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

        mpl.rcParams["lines.linewidth"] = 1
        mpl.rcParams["lines.color"] = "b"

    def plotAudio(self, waveformData):
        plot = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        plot.margins(0)
        plot.axis("off")
        plot.plot(waveformData)
```

By setting the `constrained_layout` keyword argument one can obtain the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added extra lines to my code, as follows: `self.figure.tight_layout(pad=0)
        self.plot.set_xlim([0, len(waveformData)])
        self.plot.set_ylim([waveformData.min(), waveformData.max()])
        self.plot.plot(waveformData)`  However this doesn't seem to have had any effect. Because of this I'm now wondering if PyQt margins, rather than Matplotlib margins, but be the issue.

Comment: Also, in case having the exact dataset is helpful, I've put the test WAV file here: http://www.twentypenguins.co.uk/misc/qt/937-01400_20200622091518.wav

Comment: @TwentyPenguins yes, I edited my answer to add a way in which the margins could be improved. It is not perfect though. Perhaps by digging more into PyQt5 you could recover the final millimeter to make it perfect. In any case, the `constrained_layout` argument might be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that's absolutely brilliant. `constrained_layout` was the answer. Interestingly, just changing that line of code gives me a waveform with absolutely no margins, not even the slight pixel margins in your screengrab (perhaps as a result of some of the other lines I've left in?). Thanks very much indeed for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a canvas inside the canvas unnecessarily, and that adds the margins. So the solution is to remove the unnecessary canvas:

```
class MatplotlibWidget(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MatplotlibWidget, self).__init__(Figure())
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.figure.tight_layout(pad=0)
        self.plot = None

        self.figure.set_facecolor("black")
        mpl.rcParams["lines.linewidth"] = 1
        mpl.rcParams["lines.color"] = "b"

    def plotAudio(self, waveformData):
        self.plot = self.figure.add_subplot(111, position=[0, 0, 1, 1])
        self.plot.clear()
        self.plot.axis("off")
        self.plot.use_sticky_edges = True
        self.plot.set_title(None)
        self.plot.set_xlabel(None)
        self.plot.set_ylabel(None)
        self.plot.margins(0)
        self.figure.subplots_adjust(
            left=0, right=1, top=1, bottom=0, wspace=0, hspace=0
        )
        self.figure.tight_layout(pad=0)
        self.plot.plot(waveformData)
        self.draw()
```

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]